# Writing unit tests for simple Angular functions which using inject() method in Angular 16

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine, angular16

After Angular CanActivate interface became deprecated, I've changed my guards for simple const functions based on official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#router-class-and-injectiontoken-guards-and-resolvers).
For example here is my inverseAuthGuard method, which seems working correctly:

```
export const inverseAuthGuard = (): boolean => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);
  if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
    router.navigate(['/visual-check']);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

My problem is that, I want to write some unit tests for it and I don't know how can I inject a mock authService and a mockRouter into this function. I've watched this [video](https://youtu.be/Tvsa4OMUGXs?si=fv2LlFG-O-HU4-dq), which explains how can I inject mock services into a class, but for my guard function I couldn't make it working.

I have tried some ways, but I couldn' find any solution.
If I do this way:

```
describe('InverseAuthGuard', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: AuthService },
        { provide: Router, useValue: Router },
      ],
    });
  });

  fit('should return true on not authenticated user', () => {
    const result = inverseAuthGuard();
    expect(result).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I've got the following error:

```
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`
```

If I do that way, what I saw in the [video](https://youtu.be/Tvsa4OMUGXs?si=fv2LlFG-O-HU4-dq):

```
describe('InverseAuthGuard', () => {
  const setupWithDI = (authService: unknown, router: unknown) =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: authService },
        { provide: Router, useValue: router },
      ],
    }).inject(inverseAuthGuard);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
    });
  });

  fit('should return true on not authenticated user', () => {
    const mockAuthService: unknown = { isAuthenticated: () => true };
    const mockRouter: Router = jasmine.createSpyObj(['navigate']);
    setupWithDI(mockAuthService, mockRouter);
    const result = inverseAuthGuard();
    expect(result).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I've got the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for inverseAuthGuard!
```

Of course, I've tried providing inverseAuthGuard somehow, but without any success.
I think there should be an easy solution for it, but I didn't find in any documentation. I will be thanksful for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run functions in the right injection context with the old setup that you had

```
const result = TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => inverseAuthGuard());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working :)